# no authority to raid10 array linux ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount, raid, mdadm

I have just created a Raid10 array with mdadm out of 3 X 1TB hhd, named md0. I followed these instructions: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-raid-arrays-with-mdadm-on-ubuntu-16-04

I have no authority to md0.

The array can be found at

```
/media/joe/f7790191-84f3-4d9b-81b8-43de132244a2

echo hello > hello.txt
bash: hello.txt: Permission denied
```

Actually, I can't even do this with sudo ...

```
sudo echo hello > hello.txt
bash: hello.txt: Permission denied
```

Permissions appear as they should:

```
joe@joeslinux:/media/joe$ ls -al
total 12
drwxr-x---+ 3 root root 4096 Mar 30 22:42 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Mar 28 17:26 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Mar 29 22:30 f7790191-84f3-4d9b-81b8-43de132244a2
```

Oh, and /mnt is this:

```
joe@joeslinux:/$ ls -al /mnt/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Mar 29 17:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Mar 28 20:54 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Mar 29 17:22 md0
```

`/etc/fstab` is:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=20b839d8-08f1-441e-99e3-f87f6dda9c66 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=2403be72-9dca-43b6-a596-044cfd813801 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

`sudo blkid` is:

```
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/nvme0n1: PTUUID="3acfb4f5" PTTYPE="dos"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="20b839d8-08f1-441e-99e3-f87f6dda9c66" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="3acfb4f5-01"
/dev/nvme0n1p5: UUID="2403be72-9dca-43b6-a596-044cfd813801" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="3acfb4f5-05"
/dev/sda: UUID="43468a60-e0d2-6202-4e0c-320120beeee1" UUID_SUB="11eb3ea8-74da-18c2-cd0a-bb2454c0cb46" LABEL="joeslinux:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sdb: UUID="43468a60-e0d2-6202-4e0c-320120beeee1" UUID_SUB="a49f1c1a-3450-39bc-8efb-67da1ebeacdf" LABEL="joeslinux:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/md0: UUID="f7790191-84f3-4d9b-81b8-43de132244a2" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sdc: UUID="43468a60-e0d2-6202-4e0c-320120beeee1" UUID_SUB="27ae3d15-ef03-2937-7454-ed89da25e857" LABEL="joeslinux:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
```

`sudo fdisk` -l is:

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x3acfb4f5

Device         Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1 *         2048 366155775 366153728 174.6G 83 Linux
/dev/nvme0n1p2      366157822 500117503 133959682  63.9G  5 Extended
/dev/nvme0n1p5      366157824 500117503 133959680  63.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000680a0

Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x76221e63

Disk /dev/sdc: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xee260f95

Disk /dev/md0: 1.4 TiB, 1500105408512 bytes, 2929893376 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 524288 bytes / 1572864 bytes
```

(loop0,1,2,3 entries omitted)

Is the problem staring me in the face with root:root owner? Or perhaps that fstab does not contain a UUID tying back to md0? I'm too new at this, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If the underlying filesystem of the RAID array is `ext4`, then the issue is permissions.  Items mounted in `/etc/fstab` don't get owner or group IDs by default, and if it's a Linux formatted filesystem, then you have to *set* the permissions via `chown`, etc.

You have to either change the complete ownership rights for the entire RAID array to be your user, or use `sudo` to create directories on the RAID array and then reassign ownership of the folders themselves.

Both of these options are fairly simple to achieve.

**To create a directory on the array, and set that directory to be owned by you**:

```
sudo mkdir /media/joe/f7790191-84f3-4d9b-81b8-43de132244a2/{FOLDER NAME}
sudo chown joe:joe /media/joe/f7790191-84f3-4d9b-81b8-43de132244a2/{FOLDER NAME}
```

... just make sure to replace `{FOLDER NAME}` with the name of the directory you create.

**To change the entire set of permissions on the array to be yours:**

```
sudo chown joe:joe /media/joe/f7790191-84f3-4d9b-81b8-43de132244a2/
```

This will change the entire disk array to be owned by you, which in turn will let you create files on the array, which is probably what you want to do.

Note that this will prohibit other users except `root` from writing to the array, in case you wanted to use it for other things than just your own personal storage.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. I am the only one using this home computer so I'll go with the second method. I did notice the permissions as root:root, I just wasn't sure it was apropos to just change them, thus ruining something down the line.

Comment: @JoeMolnar its fine to chown it to your user and group, if only you are using it.  Consider custom mount points owned by a system user too, but not root.  Rare cases but they still exist.  And your `sudo` did not work in your post because only the `echo` was covered by `sudo` and not the redirection to write to file.